# My Sprites Are Scrunched in Sprite Kit using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite, image-size

I am creating my first game with Sprite Kit. It is a Flappy Bird type game. The image on the left is what the game looked like earlier today. I ended up creating an entirely new project. I copied the code for the previous project and pasted it into the current one. I placed the same exact images as the previous project into the current one as well. There are no compiling errors and everything works the same except that the game now looks like the image on the right. As you can see the images widths are smaller. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, if you would like me to provide all of the code in this question let me know, thank you.

[image]

This is all of the code for the Archery Scene:

```
//
//  ArcheryScene.swift
//  FlappyBird (swift)
//
//  Created by Brandon Ballard on 1/6/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Brandon Ballard. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class ArcheryScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var bird = SKSpriteNode()
var pipeUpTexture = SKTexture()
var pipeDownTexture = SKTexture()
var pipesMoveAndRemove = SKAction()
var score = 0

let pipeGap = 150.0

enum ColliderType:UInt32 {
    case BIRD = 1
    case PIPE = 2
}


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */


    backgroundColor = SKColor.cyanColor()

    //physics
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0, -15.0);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self



    //Bird
    var birdTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Bird")
    birdTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

    bird = SKSpriteNode(texture: birdTexture)
    bird.setScale(0.6)
    bird.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width * 0.35 + 20, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.95)

    bird.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bird.size.height / 2.0)
    bird.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    bird.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = true
    bird.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
    bird.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.BIRD.rawValue
    bird.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.PIPE.rawValue
    self.addChild(bird)

    //Ground
    var groundTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ground")

    var sprite = SKSpriteNode(texture: groundTexture)
    sprite.setScale(2.0)
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, sprite.size.height / 2.0)


    self.addChild(sprite)

    var ground = SKNode()

    ground.position = CGPointMake(0, groundTexture.size().height + 0)
    ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, groundTexture.size().height * 2.0))
    ground.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    self.addChild(ground)



    //Pipes

    //Create the Pipes

    pipeUpTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "PipeUp")
    pipeDownTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "PipeDown")

    //Movement of Pipes

    let distanceToMove = CGFloat(self.frame.size.width + 2.0 * pipeUpTexture.size().width)
    let movePipes = SKAction.moveByX(-distanceToMove, y: 0.0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.01 * distanceToMove))
    let removePipes = SKAction.removeFromParent()

    pipesMoveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([movePipes,removePipes])

    //Spawn Pipes

    let spawn = SKAction.runBlock({() in self.spawnPipes()})
    let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(2.0))
    let spawnThenDelay = SKAction.sequence([spawn,delay])
    let spawnThenDelayForever = SKAction.repeatActionForever(spawnThenDelay)

    self.runAction(spawnThenDelayForever)
}

func spawnPipes() {

    let pipePair = SKNode()
    pipePair.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width + pipeUpTexture.size().width * 2, 0)
    pipePair.zPosition = -10

    let height = UInt32(self.frame.size.height / 4)
    let y = arc4random() % height + height

    var pipeDown = SKSpriteNode(texture: pipeDownTexture)
    pipeDown.setScale(2.0)////////
    pipeDown.position = CGPointMake(3.0, CGFloat(y) + pipeDown.size.height + CGFloat(pipeGap) )

    pipeDown.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pipeDown.size)
    pipeDown.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    pipeDown.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    pipeDown.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.PIPE.rawValue
    pipePair.addChild(pipeDown)

    var pipeUp = SKSpriteNode(texture: pipeUpTexture)
    pipeUp.setScale(2.0)
    pipeUp.position = CGPointMake(0.0, CGFloat(y))

    pipeUp.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: pipeUp.size )
    pipeUp.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    pipeUp.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    pipeUp.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.PIPE.rawValue
    pipePair.addChild(pipeUp)

    pipePair.runAction(pipesMoveAndRemove)
    self.addChild(pipePair)

}



func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContactDelegate) {
    scene?.view?.paused = true
    //gameOver()

}

func createScoreNode() -> SKLabelNode {
    let scoreNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Brandon Ballard")
    scoreNode.name = "scoreNode"

    let newScore = "\(score)"

    scoreNode.text = newScore
    scoreNode.fontSize = 125
    scoreNode.fontColor = SKColor.cyanColor()
    scoreNode.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 58)
    self.addChild(scoreNode)
    return scoreNode
}

func gameOver() {
    let scoreNode = self.createScoreNode()
    self.addChild(scoreNode)
    let fadeOut = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(3.0), SKAction.fadeOutWithDuration(3.0)])

    let welcomeReturn = SKAction.runBlock({
        let transition = SKTransition.revealWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down, duration: 1.0)
        let welcomeScene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
        self.scene!.view?.presentScene(welcomeScene, transition: transition)
    })

    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut, welcomeReturn])
    self.runAction(sequence)
}


override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */


    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        bird.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake( 0, 0 )
        bird.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0,25))

    }
}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */
}
}
```

Comment: Seems hard to answer without code. How do you build your transform matrix?

Comment: probably scene size (log it!) or scene.scaleMode are different

Comment: I apologize but I am new to all of this and I don't really know what a transform matrix is. However I did add in the code I hope this helps

Comment: look at my answer for this.  check out your code in GameViewController
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725318/skshapenode-using-wrong-width-and-height/27726080#27726080

Comment: Ive been trying but I haven't had any luck

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do to fix my problem was add a simple line of code to my GameScene file. Here is the code I had in the GameScene file before I solved the problem that presents the ArcheryScene:

```
welcomeNode?.runAction(fadeAway, completion: {
                let doors = SKTransition.pushWithDirection(SKTransitionDirection.Down, duration: 1.0)
                let archeryScene = ArcheryScene(fileNamed: "ArcheryScene")
                self.view?.presentScene(archeryScene, transition: doors)
            })
```

All I had to do was add this line of code after I created "archeryScene":

```
archeryScene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
```

This made the images "fit to screen size". The exact description of ".AspectFill" used by Apple is:

"The scaling factor of each dimension is calculated and the larger of the two is chosen. Each axis of the scene is scaled by the same scaling factor. This guarantees that the entire area of the view is filled but may cause parts of the scene to be cropped."